# Most Efficient Way to Return Y/N If One or More Columns Contain Non-Null Value?

Tags: sql-server, null

What is the most concise way to return CHAR(1) indicator Y/N if one of *n* columns in a row contain a non-null value?

Performance is important, but not the primary consideration, in this case.

The straightforward way seems to be:

```
SELECT      CASE WHEN (C.TerminatedDate IS NULL
                       AND C.SelfClosedDate IS NULL
                       AND ...)
                 THEN 'Y'
                 ELSE 'N' END AS 'OpenInd'

  FROM      Customers C
```

Curious if there is a better way; aware of COALESCE():

```
SELECT      CASE WHEN COALESCE (C.TerminatedDate, C.SelfClosedDate, ...) IS NULL
                 THEN 'Y'
                 ELSE 'N' END AS 'OpenInd'

  FROM      Customers C
```

Is there a better way?

Database server is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: `COALESCE ` only works if all columns have the same datatype. It gets transformed into a nested `case` (`case when C.TerminatedDate is not null then C.TerminatedDate else case when C.SelfClosedDate is not null then C.SelfClosedDate end end`) I'd have guessed that there isn't much in it.

Comment: @schultkl - By what metric are you defining "most efficient"? Most efficient to write or most efficient for the system to evaluate?

Comment: Actually `COALESCE` might cause implicit casts to happen which presumably have some expense.

Comment: @Martin - Would an implicit cast issue cause a problem if all you are checking is whether it is null or not? I.e., could an implicit cast take a non-null value and convert it to null? Afaik, it would not.

Comment: @Thomas: yes. NULL or not NULL is irrelevant. Column datatype is. The COALESCE *must* have a output datatype that applies to all columns -> some rows will have all non-NULL values -> datatype precedence applies -> all rows have that datatype, even if all vlaues are null

Comment: @gbn - My question isn't whether datatype precedence and implicit casts would take place. My question is whether it will matter in this case assuming that every value is able to be implicitly cast to something. So, it casts a int to a varchar. It is still going to be either null or not for the purposes of evaluation. Would it ever implicitly convert a non-null value to a null? Not afaik.

Comment: @Thomas: yes, it does matter that everything casts. It's datatype, no nullability. NULL or NOT NULL is actually a *constraint* on the column: not a property of the column -> has no meaning for COALESCE/conversions

Comment: @gbn - I think we are talking about two different things. I'm not talking about a nullability constraint. Assume for the moment, that everything stuffed in a given example of Coalesce will implicitly cast without error. There is no implicit cast as far as I'm aware that would convert a non-null value to a null value? I.e., would it ever occur where you had Coalesce(v1,v2,v3,...vn) *which executed without error* where say v1 and v2 are both not null but v2 was returned?

Comment: @Thomas: v1 would be returned: this is how COALESCE works. v2 would never be returned

Comment: @gbn - Right. So in this particular question's case, where the OP only cares about null/not null (even if the cast value comes out wonky), if you could get Coalesce to execute without error, it could be used to determine if any of the values are null or not. I think we both agree that if the data types are not identical, it is probably not a recommended solution.

Comment: @Thomas:  yep. (padding)

Comment: @Thomas All datatypes, in this case, are DATETIME, NULL. Thank you for asking me to clarify what I mean by "efficient." In this case, I am looking for the most concise way to write the query; execution time is important, but not my primary concern, here.

Comment: @schultkl - Given that all the columns in question are datetime, your second solution would probably be the most concise.

Comment: @Thomas - I had to go out. I was wondering whether (for example) say there was a non null `varchar(max)` column implicitly cast to `nvarchar(max)` whether it might cause some additional lob reads over and above those that are required simply in the `NOT NULL` check. Quite possibly not but I'll test that now.

Comment: @Martin - Possible. Although, if you had to mix data types in the use of Coalesce, it'd probably be best to change to a Case expression.

Comment: @Thomas - I've just checked and it does indeed seem to bring in all the lob data in that case which would make that implicit cast particularly expensive (the reason I brought up implicit casts was because the title asks about efficiency even though that the emphasis has now been placed on conciseness)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since no one is suggesting it, and the question asks for `concise`..

For the same data types, a straight COALESCE is best

```
coalesce(a,b,c,d) is not null
```

If you will be dealing with different data types, try a modified COALESCE

```
coalesce(LEFT(a,1),LEFT(b,1),LEFT(c,1)) is not null
```

Sample:

```
create table abc (a int, b datetime, c varchar(max), d image)
insert into abc select 1, GETDATE(), '', null
insert into abc select 1, null, '', null
insert into abc select 1, null, '', 0x123123
insert into abc select null, null, '', 0x123123
insert into abc select null, GETDATE(), '', 0x123123
insert into abc select null, null, null, null
insert into abc select 88, GETDATE()+3, null, null
insert into abc select 88, GETDATE()+3, 'gdasdf', null
insert into abc select null, null, '222', 0x123123
insert into abc select null, null, 'abcdef', 0x123123

select *, case when coalesce(LEFT(a,1),LEFT(b,1),LEFT(c,1)) is not null then 'N' else 'Y' end
from abc
```

If you are not using exotic types like VARCHAR(MAX) or IMAGE, then you can use SQL_VARIANT with COALESCE

```
create table abc (a int, b datetime, c varchar(10), d image)
insert into abc select 1, GETDATE(), '', null
insert into abc select 1, null, '', null
insert into abc select 1, null, '', 0x123123
insert into abc select null, null, '', 0x123123
insert into abc select null, GETDATE(), '', 0x123123
insert into abc select null, null, null, null
insert into abc select 88, GETDATE()+3, null, null
insert into abc select 88, GETDATE()+3, 'gdasdf', null
insert into abc select null, null, '222', 0x123123
insert into abc select null, null, 'abcdef', 0x123123

select *, case when coalesce(convert(sql_variant,a),b,c) is not null then 'N' else 'Y' end
from abc
```

Comment: Thanks Richard; this is a very clever answer. I like it. The LEFT(...) changes all data types to VARCHAR(1), right? And sql_variant(...) forces COALESCE(...) to return datatype sql_variant?

Comment: Thank you--I deleted my original comment when I realized the same thing. :o) On my system, the "select *" returned "2011-03-08 12:10:03.713", so I initially guessed it was interpreting the first byte as a character. Thank you for pointing out the implicit conversion to VARCHAR.

Comment: And now I see you deleted your comment; ha! ;o)

Comment: @schultkl Re your first comment, yes and yes. SQL_VARIANT doesn't work with some exotic types

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, you should get the advantages of short-circuiting here by immediately returning when any value is not null

```
Select Case
        When C.TerminatedDate Is Not Null Then 'N'
        When C.SelfClosedDate Is Not Null Then 'N'
        ...
        Else 'Y'
        End
```

That said, I doubt there is a significant difference in performance between this solution and your above solutions (assuming you can use Coalesce).

Comment: Thanks Thomas; this was my first thought, as well. Curious if a more elegant/concise solution was available. Sounds like this is a pretty good trade-off though, for performance and clarity (but not brevity, as much). :o)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a "outside the box" solution. A persisted computed column.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
  [CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Date1] [datetime] NULL,
  [Date2] [datetime] NULL,
  [AllNulls]  AS (case when [date1] IS NULL AND [date2] IS NULL then 'Y' else 'N' end) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Cusomter] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
    [CustomerID] ASC
 )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael; excellent idea. We may have the opportunity to do something like this in the future. Presently, we have a support contract for maintaining the database, so modifications of this nature can only be made by the contractor.

Answer (score 2):

Without further information, the former (a case statement) is the most efficient means in MS SQL Server.
(Although with the same assumptions, I personally would return it as a bit value and perform conversion to Y/N, which is really a display representation or viewmodel concern.)

Now, if filtering is going to be done repeatedly, and for performance reasons it is appropriate to do so at the database engine, performing the NULL test in the where clause would improve things further.  If you have many of these, you could consider aggregating them on update (via a persisted computed column beautifully suggested by another answerer, Stored Proc, data model, or heaven forbid a trigger).

Comment: Thanks Shannon, for the idea of returning a bit value, and for also suggesting the computed column idea.

Answer (score 1):

If all columns are datetime, this works unless the total overflows. Note zero = 01 Jan 1900 so there is a lot of headroom before 31 Dec 9999

NULL added to any other expression gives NULL

```
SELECT
    CASE
         WHEN C.TerminatedDate + C.SelfClosedDate + C.OtherDate + .. IS NULL THEN
                 THEN 'Y'
                 ELSE 'N'
         END AS 'OpenInd'

  FROM      Customers C
```

Comment: Thanks gbn; I find this a very creative answer--something I never would have come up with! :o)

Answer (score 1):

One  case where the concise coalesce approach could definitely hurt performance is dealing with off row data that also requires an implicit cast.

```
CREATE TABLE coalescetest
(
id int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
bigvarchar1 varchar(max) NULL,
bigvarchar2 varchar(max) NULL,
bignvarchar1 Nvarchar(max) NULL,
bignvarchar2 Nvarchar(max) NULL
)

INSERT INTO coalescetest
SELECT TOP 100
     REPLICATE(CAST('A' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),12000),
     REPLICATE(CAST('A' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),12000),
     REPLICATE(CAST('A' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),12000),
     REPLICATE(CAST('A' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),12000)   
FROM master..spt_values             

SET STATISTICS IO ON    

SELECT      id, CASE WHEN COALESCE (bigvarchar1,bigvarchar2,bignvarchar1,bignvarchar2) IS NULL
                 THEN 'Y'
                 ELSE 'N' END AS Result

FROM coalescetest
```

Gives

> Table 'coalescetest'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical reads 0, 
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads **400**, lob physical reads 0, 
>   lob read-ahead reads **300**.

```
SELECT      CASE WHEN (bigvarchar1 IS NULL
                       AND bigvarchar2 IS NULL
                       AND bignvarchar1 IS NULL
                       AND bignvarchar2 IS NULL)
                 THEN 'Y'
                 ELSE 'N' END AS Result
  FROM     coalescetest
```

Gives

> Table 'coalescetest'. Scan count 1,
>   logical reads 5, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads
>   **0**, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads **0**.